# Pushing logs to cloudwatch from spring boot application with role based access

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, spring-logback

This is my requirement - I need my spring boot application to push all logs to cloudwatch using log appenders. I will be giving the key, secret, log group and stream in application.properties.

Current Setup:

I have 2 appenders in my logback-spring.xml(CONSOLE and cloudwatch). I need console to run in all profiles, and cloudwatch to run in only `production` profile. So I used a `springProfile` wrapper. The appender class is a class I created with @Configuration annotation. I am accepting access key, secret, loggroup and stream using @Value. As you might have already guessed my problem is that logback-spring.xml is initialised first. By then my appender class is not initialized(once I removed @value and gave hard coded values it was working but I dont want to do that). I understand it is because of the initialization order, but unsure how to move forward in this scenario.

1. Is there a way to make the appender class initialize first? (Is that even a right approach?)
2. Is there a way to get the config inside appender using `springProperty` and then somehow pass that to my cloudwatch appender class(instead of using @value)?
3. Is there any better way / is my approach to the problem wrong?

This is my appender:

```
        <appender name="cloudwatch" class="com.project.CloudWatchAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
            </filter>
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="cloudwatch"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
```

And here is my `CloudWatchAppender` from [blog](https://mahfuzcse12.medium.com/sending-spring-boot-application-logs-to-aws-cloudwatch-49f5a018b983)

```
public class CloudWatchAppender extends UnsynchronizedAppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${cloudwatch.accesskey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${cloudwatch.accesssecret}")
    private String accessSecret;

    @Value("${cloudwatch.loggroup}")
    private String logGroupName;

    @Value("${cloudwatch.logstream}")
    private String logStreamName;

    private CloudWatchLogsClient client;

    private Queue<InputLogEvent> eventQueue;

    public CloudWatchAppender() {
        client = CloudWatchLogsClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                        AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey,
                                accessKey)))
                .region(Region.of(awsRegion))
                .build();
        eventQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(final ILoggingEvent event) {
        // Construct the log message
        InputLogEvent logEvent = InputLogEvent.builder()
                .message(event.getLevel().levelStr + " " + event.getFormattedMessage())
                .timestamp(event.getTimeStamp())
                .build();

        // Add event to the queue
        eventQueue.add(logEvent);

        // Flush queue if it has more than 10 events - Prod
        /*
        if (eventQueue.size() >= 10) {
            flushEvents();
        }
        */
        // Flush queue - Dev
        flushEvents();
    }

    private void flushEvents() {
        // Retrieve the existing log events
        DescribeLogStreamsResponse describeLogStreamsResponse = client.describeLogStreams(DescribeLogStreamsRequest
        .builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName)
                .build());

        String sequenceToken = describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams().get(0).uploadSequenceToken();

        // Batch up the next 10 events
        LinkedList<InputLogEvent> logEventsBatch = new LinkedList<>();
        while (!eventQueue.isEmpty() && logEventsBatch.size() < 10) {
            logEventsBatch.add(eventQueue.poll());
        }

        // Check if logEventsBatch is empty
        if (logEventsBatch.isEmpty()) {
            return; // Skip the API call if there are no log events
        }

        // Put the log events into the CloudWatch stream
        PutLogEventsRequest putLogEventsRequest = PutLogEventsRequest.builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamName(logStreamName)
                .logEvents(logEventsBatch)
                .sequenceToken(sequenceToken)
                .build();

        client.putLogEvents(putLogEventsRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // Flush any remaining events before stopping
        flushEvents();

        // Clean up the AWS CloudWatchLogs client
        client.close();

        super.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Value keeps returning null. Took the variables using System.getenv and it worked